# R subset and sum without resorting to for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, tidyverse

I have the following dataset:

```
      col1    col2    col3    col4
row1    x     True    Yes      0.4
row1    y     False   No       0.3
row1    z     True    Yes      0.5
```

Where columns 1 to 3 have a fixed set of values. I need to subset all possible combinations of these fixed values and then sum the amounts in column4 that remain. For example, if I were to do this one at a time, manually:

```
subset1 <- data %>% 
  filter(col1 == 'x' & col2== True & col3== 'Yes') %>%
  pull(col4) %>%
  sum

subset2 <- data %>% 
  filter(col1 == 'y' & col2== False & col3== 'No') %>%
  pull(col4) %>%
  sum

subset3 <- data %>% 
  filter(col1 == 'z' & col2== True & col3== 'Yes') %>%
  pull(col4) %>%
  sum
```

However, the actual dataset contains a dozen columns with a fixed list of around a dozen values each. Subsetting these manually would require a few hundred lines of almost identical code. Is there a way to produce these subset tables with a simple function?  Something similar to:

```
list1 <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
list2 <- c(True, False)
list3 <- c("Yes", "No")


f1 <- function(data, list1, list2, list3){
  table <- timeline %>% 
    filter(col1 %in% list1 & col2 %in% list2 & col3 %in% list3) %>%
    pull(col4) %>%
    sum
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to try the below code and see if it works:

```r
yourdf <- yourdf%>%
  group_by(yourColumn)%>%
  summarize(newColumn=sum(columnTobeSummed))
```

Do let us know if it works!Good Luck

Comment: Clarification/Correction Update:  assign it to a new df rather than yourdf  as mentioned... so newdf <- yourdf..... It will create a new df with what you want - hopefully.